# On Presatshop: i made PHP page for create TXT file. On local it works, but on server do not write

Tags: php, mysql, export, prestashop

I made PHP page for create TXT file. On local it works, but on server do not write.
I put here initial part of PHP file... Help Please.
I'd like to write orders file in a specifc folder on serve. In local I can do it on root.. Help me please... thanks

If is necessary i put all PHP code on my file, thanks

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "zzxxx";
$pass = "";
$db = "zzxxx";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
unset($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$query = "SELECT id_order, id_address_delivery FROM ps_orders WHERE saved_as_txt = 0";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id_order = $row['id_order']; // salva ID order come variabile
$id_address_delivery = $row['id_address_delivery'];
$filename = $id_order.".txt";

$file = fopen($filename,"w");

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ps_address WHERE id_address = " . $id_address_delivery;

$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{

    fwrite($file, "PROVA" . "|");

.......
......
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Check owner of directory and rights your script is trying to save file to. It should be web server, with privileges to write.

If you're on unix machine it goes like this:

```
 $ sudo chown your_webserver_name /path/to/directory/
```

EDIT:
It does't matter if you as root have access to folder where you want to save your files, because when you run your PHP script, it works on behalf of web server (probably apache), and that's why you should change owner of your folder you saving your files to.

Comment: on server i have other script that write a files, how can i check/modify it? thanks

Comment: I have 777 on folder but it not write.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your script cannot write to the specified directory. If you aren't seeing any errors, you can turn them on by adding this to the top of your PHP script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can read more about turning error reporting on and off here: [PHP: error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

It's worth noting that you generally want some error reporting on during development, and all error reporting off in production.

Comment: I have 777 on folder but it not write.

Comment: Are you running this script via a HTTP request? If so you should see some error reporting in the HTTP response if you add the error_reporting() line above. This is a good place to begin debugging.

Comment: Also it doesn't seem like you're specifying a folder to write to, just a filename. $filename needs to be the full directory path to the file you wish to write to. eg. /home/username/www/output/file.txt